Improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec x}{x}dx$.
I would like to know the nature of the improper integral $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec x}{x}dx$$
I tried to use the limit form comparison test by letting $f(x)=\frac{\sec x}{x}$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. Then since $f(x)=\frac{\sec x}{x}$ is positive in [0,1] and
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$$
Therefore by limit form comparison test both the integrals $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)$ and $\int_{0}^{1} g(x)$ behave alike.Since,$\int_{0}^{1} g(x)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}$ is divergent. Therefore, $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec x}{x}dx$, is divergent.
Is the above conclusion correct? I would also like to know if there are better ways to tackle this problem. Thank you in advance.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

As $x\to 0^+$ $\frac{\sec x}x \sim \frac 1x$

@SineoftheTime Got it sir.Thank you

Yes, this integral diverges. Your answer is correct. You may also look at it like this:
Notice that $\frac{\sec{x}}{x}=\frac{1}{\cos{x}}\frac{1}{x}$. Since
$$0<\cos{1}\leq \cos{x}\leq 1,\qquad \forall 0\leq x\leq 1,$$
then $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sec{x}}{x} dx$  has the same character as $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x} dx$, which diverges of course.

By comparison test?

Yes, since $\frac{1}{x}\frac{1}{\cos{x}}>\frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,1]$.
